# jqPlot - Is there a way to label only specific bar graphs?

Tags: jqplot

My jqPlot graph contains 200 vertical bars.  I colour the shorted bar in green, the longest in red and other in yellow.

If I do

```
pointLabels: {
    show: true
}
```

then I get 200 point labels, which are all squashed together and not readable.

Is it possible to label only the shortest and the longest bars?

I've read this page but been unable to find a solution:

[http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html#$.jqplot.PointLabels.seriesLabelIndex](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pointLabels-js.html#%24.jqplot.PointLabels.seriesLabelIndex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you when passing 'ticks' to the chart set some ticks to empty string `""`.
Also I recommend you using this settings to rotate your labels of the ticks:

```
tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
tickOptions: {
  angle: -45
}
```

Comment: Thanks again :)  I believe what you mean here is 'labels' not 'ticks'.  But your suggestion was very helpful to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Yea you are right. You can apply the same approach with empty string to point labels as well. Thought when it goes to rotation I have been using this renderer for the ticks under the bar only.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is interested, this is what I did:

```
var shortest = 5; // find shortest somehow
var longest = 10; // find longest somehow

var myLabels = [];
for (var i = 0; i < histogramData.length; i++) {
    myLabels[i] = "";
}

myLabels[shortest] = shortest;
myLabels[longest] = longest;
```

And then set the following jqPlot option:

```
pointLabels: {
    show: true,
    labels: myLabels,
    hideZeros: true
}
```

The only drawback is that **this makes zooming a bit slower** when you have many x axis entries like my case.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that jqplot doesn't support for smart axis rendering which means truncating labels so the adjacent labels will not clash together. But you can use angle options so the labels won't clash. But for a large set of data it won't work either. The jqplot only calculates the necessary axis ticks regardless of the container size which the chart is going to be plot.

```
 If you have worked with Google chart or like thing you can see they are not prioritizing axis ticks or something, they calculate the axis according to data and the plot area both. So the answer is even if you angle the tick labels you will come up with a limit. I'm not saying cheers! for this
```

Sorry!..